# How to use LowprofileImageLoader and Image Place holder together in wp7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

How can we use LowprofileImageLoader and Image Place holder together in wp7 app?
I have gone through [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/09/02/keep-a-low-profile-lowprofileimageloader-helps-the-windows-phone-7-ui-thread-stay-responsive-by-loading-images-in-the-background.aspx) and [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2011/09/08/know-your-place-in-life-free-placeimage-control-makes-it-easy-to-add-placeholder-images-to-any-wpf-silverlight-or-windows-phone-application.aspx) link but unable to use together.
But people have said in comments that they are able to use both by changing the following code in PlaceImage.cs:

```
if (null != _frontImage)

       {

           if (!System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))

           {

               Delay.LowProfileImageLoader.SetUriSource(this, ((BitmapImage)this.Source).UriSource);

           }

       }
```

But when I do so, I got invalid arguments error. Can somebody suggest me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
if (null != _frontImage)
{
    if (!System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
    {
        Delay.LowProfileImageLoader.SetUriSource(_frontImage, ((BitmapImage) this.Source).UriSource);
    }
}
```

It's the _frontImage's UriSource that you want to set.